# best way to select random, corresponding data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to have something like:

```
category = ("word1","word2","word3")
       ("definition1","definition2","definition3");
category1 = ("word1","word2","word3")
       ("definition1","definition2","definition3");
```

the basic goal is to select and output (lets just say 3) random words from any random category and be able to call on their relevant data as i develop it more (the category name and the definition of the word that was chosen randomly).

i also don't want duplicates, and i appreciate all suggestions! :) 
thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to create arrays here? Because if so you want `[` and `]` instead of parentheses...

Comment: I'm way too lazy atm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array. Oh and if you're asking yourself, since both array elements are in correct order you can select the word and corresponding definition with the same index...

Answer (score 3):

You want a structure that is an array of objects:

```
category1 = [
    { word: "word1", definition: "def1" },
    { word: "word2", definition: "def2" },
    { word: "word3", definition: "def3" }
];
```

Then, to select a value from `category1`, pick some `category1[i]` at random and use `category1[i].word` and `category1[i].definition`.

You can extend each object to have additional properties later as needed (`numberOfSylables`, `gradeLevel`, etc.)